# Change State when socket io event emitted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets

I am working on a chat application with React Js and Socket.io-client. So I made the chat component and in it -

1. A state variable messages ( array of object that saves all messages )

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import * as Socket from "../../../Utils/socket";

import styles from "./Chat.module.css";

class Chat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      messages: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    Socket.connect();
  };


  render() {
    return (
      // Code
    );
  }
}

export default Chat;
```

I made another config file to save all the socket related functions named socket.js.

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { chatEndpoint } from "./ApiEndpointsAndURLs";

import { getDecryptedToken } from "./Encryption";

const socket = io(chatEndpoint, {
  query: `token=${getDecryptedToken()}`,
});

export const connect = () => {

  socket.on("NEW_MESSAGE", (data) => {
    // How can I set the state and the messages array ?? 
  });

};

export const emitMessage = (data) => {
  socket.emit("SEND_MESSAGE", () => {
    // Here Also ?? I want to update the array so that I can see my message
  });
};
```

So Whenever a message is typed by some other person I can catch it by " NEW_MESSAGE " event. But how do I set the state from this file ?

If you have any idea or a new way to make the chat functionality please share with me.

Thank You in advance. Even you reading it was a help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try creating a function to change the state inside your Chat component and passing that function to the emitSocket and connect functions as parameter where they can be used as callback.

Comment: Can you add an example. Also how will you pass callback to socket.on() function ??